# Application of Gershgorin theorems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

In the notes of my class, I've read the following application of Gershgorin theorems

> If $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a strictly (row) diagonally dominant and its diagonal elements are in the semiplane $Re(z)>0$, then also the eigenvalues of $A$ are in the semiplane $Re(z)>0$.

Clearly the centers of the Gershgorin circles are in the semiplane $Re(z)>0$. Then my notes state that the strict diagonal dominance imposes that the Gershgorin circles cannot "escape" the semiplane $Re(z)>0$.

But I don't understand this implication. The strict diagonal dominance just implies that the radii of the Gershgorin circles are less than the distance of their center from the origin. Basically the Gershgorin circles cannot contain the origin.

Am I missing something here or the statement is simply false?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Probably I'm not gonna remember this irregular form though... when a word ends with -s, I always use -es to construct the plural.

Comment: If you have a bus and you buy another, you get two bi.

Comment: The diagonal elements in the mentioned claim should be real.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: the eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{1+2i&-2i\\ 2i&1+2i}$ are $3+2i$ and $-1+2i$.